# Using inotifywait's output within a Bash script to delete specific file

Tags: bash

I currently have my music organised by record label and a playlist file (generated from a bash script) exists in each label's folder and has the same name as the parent folder. If I add or modify any files or folders, I need to delete that playlist and run the script to pick up any changes that have occurred.

My directory tree looks like this, the playlist has the same name as it's parent folder and contains the information about the releases.

```
Labels/
├── Label A
│   ├── Label A.playlist
│   ├── Release A
│   ├── Release B
│   └── Release C
├── Label B
│   ├── Label B.playlist
│   ├── Release A
│   ├── Release B
│   └── Release C
└── Label C
    ├── Label C.playlist
    ├── Release A
    ├── Release B
    └── Release C
```

Just incase I miss a playlist whilst importing or modifying music, I wondered if there was anything that would tell me something has been changed and automatically delete the playlist. After alot of searching, inotifywait seemed to fit the bill. I've spent most of the day getting my head around it and I finally got somewhere but there is a catch.

If I add new files/folders to any of the folders under labels, then when implementing the rm command I need the dirname of the $fullpath to delete the existing playlist. Whereas if I modify any files (ID3 tags for example) I need the dirname of the dirname of the $fullpath. Whilst the code works for what I want it to do, I would like it a bit sleeker.

```
inotifywait -m -r --format "%e %w%f" /media/C_Drive/Link_to_Music/Sorted1 -e modify -e create -e move -e delete |
while read event fullpath; do

#Remove playlist when changes to folder are reported...
rm "$(dirname "$fullpath")"/"$(basename "$(dirname "$fullpath")")".playlist   


#Remove playlist when changes to file are reported...
rm "$(dirname "$(dirname "$fullpath")")/$(basename "$(dirname "$(dirname "$fullpath")")").playlist"

done
```

Updated script.....

```
#!/bin/sh

inotifywait -m -r --format "%e %w%f" /media/C_Drive/Link_to_Music/Sorted1 -e modify -e create -e move -e delete |
while read -r event fullpath; do

folderdir=${fullpath%/*}
filedir=${folderdir%/*}
modified="MODIFY"
filedelete="DELETE"
filemoved_to="MOVED_TO"
filemoved_from="MOVED_FROM"
folmoved_to="MOVED_TO,ISDIR"
folmoved_from="MOVED_FROM,ISDIR"
foldelete="DELETE,ISDIR"

if [ "$event" = $modified ] || [ "$event" = $filedelete ] || [ "$event" = $filemoved_to ] || [ "$event" = $filemoved_from ] ;then

echo "Because the file ${fullpath##*/} was $event, ${filedir##*/}.playlist has been deleted from the folder $filedir"

# Remove playlist when changes to file...
rm "$filedir"/"${filedir##*/}".playlist

elif [ "$event" = $folmoved_to ] || [ "$event" = $folmoved_from ] || [ "$event" = $foldelete ];then

echo "Because the folder ${fullpath##*/} was $event, ${folderdir##*/}.playlist has been deleted from the folder $folderdir"

#Remove playlist when changes to folder...
rm "$folderdir"/"${folderdir##*/}".playlist

fi
done
```

Comment: Aside: `$(...)` is expensive. You certainly don't want to do it more than once in the same script if you can avoid it (and you can certainly avoid it here). `${fullpath%/*}` is **much** faster to run than `"$(dirname "$fullpath")"`, though it doesn't handle the corner case of converting a path with no `/`s to `.` correctly. (Similarly, `dirname` and `basename` aren't built into the shell, so using them incurs external-process-startup overhead).

Comment: Second, related to correctness -- consider using the `-r` argument to `read` to prevent backslashes from being munged (as happens unconditionally by default).

Comment: Third, it's noteworthy that `inotifywait` doesn't support any completely unambiguous output format (which would need to be NUL-delimited so filenames with literal newlines can't throw things off) at all. See ticket at https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/issues/20

Comment: Anyhow, one thing that would improve your code's readability -- a lot -- is to store calculated values in variables. That lets you assign those values meaningful names, and means you don't keep repeating yourself so much.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for your reply, made things a bit more readable! I'm a bit confused by your second reply. Where and how would I use the -r argument? Instead of the piped inotify output?

Comment: By default, `read` treats backslashes as significant; `read -r` disables that behavior. See [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: BTW, you might run your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fix what it finds. `[` doesn't have special parser behavior -- it's just a command -- so you still need to quote your expansions in its arguments. (`[[` is a newer alternative that *doesn't* require quotes to prevent string-splitting and globbing, though they can still be needed on the right-hand side of `=` or `=~` to specify that your value should be treated as literal rather than a pattern or regex, respectively).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy All good now, no errors reported when I ran it through shellcheck. Honestly thanks for your help!